# Creating a time slot booking system

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a system which allows an administrator to add resources which can be sold in time slots. The variables are start time, end time and interval (x minutes). A front end user will go to the site, select a resource and a date and view the available slots.

I can easily generate an array of possible slots be looping from start time to end time in x minute intervals.

Where it gets tricky for me is excluding some times from the available slots. There are the standard bookings - 1 slot at a time, but there will also be periods when the resource will be unavailable, so one booking could take up 10 time slots.

My thinking was to first generate the array of possible slots, then query the DB, removing time slots that have already been booked. This would involve splitting each longer booking into chunks.

I'm wondering if there's a pure MYSQL way to do this or at least make it as efficient and flexible as possible.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if I understand your situation, but you could have a table for possible slots with a field, 'is_booked'.  'is_booked' default would be '0'.  Set 'is_booked' to 1 when the slot is taken.

Comment: Sorry, I also don't get the problem. Is it a data modelling problem, i.e. you need help wrt. how to store the data or is it a search problem, i.e. how to find available slots?

Comment: I don't want to create the empty slots in a database - there would be over 200 per day, 7 days a week. Only boked slots will be recorded. The issue I'm having is displaying only the available slots on the front end.